# Why does grep not work with redirection?

Tags: bash, grep

Using the `top` command with redirection works fine:

```
top > top.log
```

Now I want to use grep to filter a certain line:

```
top | grep "my_program" > top.log
```

But the log file will remain empty. But grep delivers an output when using

```
top | grep "my_program"
```

Where `my_program` has to be replaced by a running program to see some output.

Why does my approach not work ? And how can I fix it ?

Comment: I just tried it, and it works for me. However, you should probably look at `-b` option to `top` or using `ps` instead.

Comment: `-b` did not solve my problem, but solved some encoding problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I get the same behavior that you describe. On Ubuntu 11.10

```
top | grep "my_program" > top.log
```

does not produce any output.

I believe the reason for this is that grep is buffering its output. To tell GNU grep to spit out output line-by-line, use the `--line-buffered` option:

```
top | grep --line-buffered "my_program" > top.log
```

---

See also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/972370/190597) for other potential solutions.

Comment: +1 `--line-buffered` solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem for me, too. The `-b` option is still a good advice from Lev Levitsky, too. That solved some encoding problems with the log file.

Answer (score 2):

you should use:

```
top -n 1 | grep "blah" > top.log
```

the "-n 1" runs top for one iteration and then quits instead of continually updating every few seconds

since you're just looking for one line though ps would be a better tool to use.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround for this problem was:

```
while :;do top -b -n 1 | grep "my_program" >> top.log;done &
```

By this way I could have a running monitor in the background for my_program and keep all results in the file top.log.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
top | grep "my_program" 2>&1 > top.log
```

[What means `2>&1`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21/818284#818284)

Answer (score 0):

Although both work for me, I think Lev Levitsky's advice is the correct one. Use the `-b` argument.

There is a good chance that output redirection is the problem and that you're not getting anything through stdout, so try this instead:

```
top -b 2>&1 | grep "my_program" > top.log
```

Do note that you might have problems with output buffering aswell. Your shell won't constantly write to the file so it could take a while for `top.log` to fill.